# Given a sorted array of n elements, write a function to search a given element x in array

Tags: c#, data-structures, binary-search, array-algorithms

**Problem Solving:** Given a sorted array of n elements, write a function to search a given element x in array.

$finding an element in a given sorted array.

$finding first or last occurrence of a number.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: My guess would be the question is why this isn't always working. If you call the first `Exists` to find the value `1` in the array `[0, 1]` I think it'll incorrectly return `-1`. Can't check or help though since I'm on my phone

Comment: @Knoop i checked it, it works fine

Comment: @WaelMourad You're right I read that wrong. So basically the question wasn't a question at all, but an attempt at writing a blog on stackoverflow?

Answer (score -1):

## Algorithms: Binary Search:

**Problem Solving:** Given a sorted array of n elements, write a function to search a given element x in array.

A simple approach is to do linear search.The time complexity of above algorithm is O(n).
Another approach to perform the same task is using Binary Search.

**Binary Search:**
Search a sorted array by repeatedly dividing the search interval in half.
Begin with an interval covering the whole array.
If the value of the search key is less than the item in the middle of the interval, narrow the interval to the lower half.
Otherwise narrow it to the upper half. Repeatedly check until the value is found or the interval is empty.

...

Binary search works on a sorted array. The value is compared with the middle element of the array.
If equality is not found, then the half part is eliminated in which the value is not there.
In the same way, the other half part is searched.

The idea of binary search is to use the information that the array is sorted and reduce the time complexity to O(Log n).

We basically ignore half of the elements just after one comparison:

1. Compare x with the middle element.
2. If x matches with middle element, we return the mid index.
3. Else If x is greater than the mid element, then x can only lie in right half sub-array after the mid element. So we recur for right half.
4. Else (x is smaller) recur for the left half.

[image: Binary Search]

```
   public class BinarySearch
   {
    #region helpers.

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns index of x if it is present in int[], else return -1,
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="array">array of sorted numbers</param>
    /// <param name="l">start index</param>
    /// <param name="r">end index</param>
    /// <param name="x">searched number</param>
    /// <returns>index of x</returns>
    public static int Exist(int[] array, int l, int r, int x)
    {
        while (l <= r)
        {
            int med = (l + r) / 2;
            // Check if x is present at mid
            if (x == array[med])
                return med;
            // If x is smaller, ignore right half
            if (x < array[med])
                r = (med - 1);
            // If x greater, ignore left half
            else
                l = (med + 1);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns index of first or last occurrence of a number if it is 
        present in int[], else return -1,    
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="array">array of sorted numbers</param>
    /// <param name="l">start index</param>
    /// <param name="r">end index</param>
    /// <param name="x">searched number</param>
    /// <param name="first">Boolean: true if searching first occurrence 
            or false if last</param>
    /// <returns>index of x</returns>
    public static int Exist(int[] array, int l, int r, int x, bool first)
    {
        int result = -1;
        while (l <= r)
        {
            int med = (l + r) / 2;
            // Check if x is present at mid
            if (x == array[med])
            {
                result = med;
                if (first)
                    r = (med - 1); //ignore right half
                else
                    l = (med + 1); //ignore left half
            }
            else if (x < array[med])
                r = (med - 1);
            else
                l = (med + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

...

```
class Program
{
    #region props.
    public BinarySearch BinarySearch { get; set; }        
    #endregion
    #region cst.
    public Program()
    {
        this.BinarySearch = new BinarySearch();
    }
    #endregion

    #region publics
    public static void Main()
    {
        //int[] array = { 2, 3, 4, 10, 40 };
        //int count = array.Length - 1;
        //var result = BinarySearch.Exist(array, 0, count, 4); 

        int[] array = { 2, 10, 10, 10, 40 };
        int count = array.Length - 1;
        var result = BinarySearch.Exist(array, 0, count, 40, false);

        Console.WriteLine(result == -1 ? "Element not present" : 
         $"Element 
        found at index {result}");
        Console.ReadKey();                      
    } 
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Some of this seems to be copied from the internet (e.g. [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/complexity-analysis-of-binary-search/)). Copying without attribution is plagiarism, which is forbidden.